# Warning message when showing a value attached from controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the controller I add a (numerical) value to the controller:

```
this.myValue = Number(elem.toFixed(2));
```

I put it inside an input form:

```
    <input class="my-input"
           type="number"
           value={{$ctrl.myValue}}
        ...
   >
```

the value is correct, everything is shown as expected on the screen but I got this warning message in console:

> The specified value "{{$ctrl.myValue}}" is not a valid number. The
>   value must match to the following regular expression:
>   -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: you input field doesn't even need a `value` attribute, change it to `ng-model="$ctrl.myValue"`

Comment: This probably happens when your value isn't initialized yet, so it is `null` or `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$scope.myValue = 0;
```

in the controller to initialize the variable.and then use it as -

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myValue" >
```

Then you can access it anywhere in the controller using $scope.myValue.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Aleksey Solovey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495123/aleksey-solovey), if `value` is changed to an `ng-model` and curly brackets are replaced by quotes the warning message disappear in this case.

```
    <input class="my-input"
           type="number"
           ng-model="$ctrl.myValue"
        ...
   >
```